# Prevent Bound ComboBox from firing SelectionChanged Event at application startup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` bound to a `ViewModel` `Items Source` `List`.

The `ComboBox` also has a `SelectionChanged Event`.

I want the event to fire only when the user has clicked the `ComboBox` and selected a new item.

But the event fires at application startup when the bound items are loaded and the default item is programmatically selected.

---

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboDisplay"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Display_Items}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Display_SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="10,10,0,0"
          Height="22" 
          Width="100" 
          SelectionChanged="cboDisplay_SelectionChanged" />
```

**C#**

```
private void cboDisplay_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
      MessageBox.Show("Event Fired");
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // Default Item at Startup
        Display_SelectedItem = "Windowed";
    }


    // Items Source
    //
    private List<string> _Display_Items = new List<string>()
    {
        "Fullscreen",
        "Windowed"
    };  
    public List<string> Display_Items
    {
        get { return _Display_Items; }
        set
        {
            _Display_Items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Display_Items");
        }
    }


    // Selected Item
    //
    private string _Display_SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public string Display_SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _Display_SelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (_Display_SelectedItem == value)
            {
              return;
            }

            _Display_SelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Display_SelectedItem");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't really change how events are fired. But you could have a `static bool` private member variable which is set to `false` at first, and is set to `true` once your initial loading of items completed. Then in the combo box's `SelectionChanged` even, you check if the said variable is `true`, and proceed with what you want to do only if it's true.

Comment: Attach the SelectionChanged event handler in a Loaded event handler. Why do you need it at all, when you already have a view model property bound to SelectedValue? Note also that you would usually bind SelectedItem, not SelectedValue (which would be used in conjunction with SelectedValuePath). Besides that, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is redundant.

Comment: @Clemens How do you mean, can you show an example?

Comment: Attach a handler to the Window's Loaded event. In the handler method, call `cboDisplay.SelectionChanged += cboDisplay_SelectionChanged;`

Comment: @Clemens I have `Window_Loaded`, but I have to see a full example, I don't know how to do any of that.

Comment: It's easy. Remove the `SelectionChanged="cboDisplay_SelectionChanged"` from your `XAML`. So when the form loads, the `SelectionChanged` event does not get triggered. Then in the form's `Loaded` event, which itself fires after the completion of loading, you attach the `SelectionChanged` event of the combo box to the event handler. So simply add the `cboDisplay.SelectionChanged += cboDisplay_SelectionChanged;` line into the `Loaded` even of your window.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks, it looks to be working now.